# How to use other people's react components in my dash app?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, styled-components, plotly-dash

I would like to include a 5-star user editable rating in my dash app, similar to what's asked in this [thread](https://community.plotly.com/t/5-star-rating-in-dash/48620) which leads to this [github page](https://github.com/ertanhasani/react-stars) where someone seem to have built it.

However, I am not sure how to leverage the work that person has done. [Documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/plugins) on official website focuses on how to **build** such components. Many blogs like [this one](https://markgituma.medium.com/adding-custom-components-to-python-dash-cfafdbfb22f9) also seem to give you tutorials on how to create such components.

What are the steps one should follow to **leverage** other people's react components into a dash app? There is a plethora of those components outthere (good list [here](https://github.com/brillout/awesome-react-components)) so I assume there is an easy way to use them in my apps, just not sure how.

PS: apologies if I am just confused by the lenghty instructions. I am very familiar with dash and python, not at all with react and javascript...

Comment: You can use a package manager like `npm` or `yarn` to use packages that have been published like the one you mentioned (`react-stars`). Try looking at this https://nodesource.com/blog/an-absolute-beginners-guide-to-using-npm/ and then eventually you can simply run `npm install react-rating-stars-component --save`

Comment: Thanks @suuuriam, but once the component is installed through npm, how do I import in my python dash code as I do for any other component? That's the part that is unclear to me. Just to be 100% clear, how do I import the react-start component and include it in the app layout. I am used to built in component like say [dcc.Collapse](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/collapse/) but not sure how to do that for those installed through npm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up asking on the Plotly community forum. See solution provided here: https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-use-other-peoples-react-components-in-my-dash-app/65627/2